# ¿Como puedo borrar el cache del navegador de Microsoft Edge por medio de HTML?

Tags: html5, cache

Estoy corriendo una aplicación en Microsoft Edge que por motivos laborales no puede ejecutarse en ningún otro explorador. El proyecto ya estaba empezado cuando yo lo tomé y se me pide obtener siempre la ultima versión de la aplicación cada vez que se de click al botón refresh. Ahora bien tambien estoy limitado en uso de javascript y solo puedo ingresar HTML5. He utilizado este meta tag        `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />` y funciona bien para explorer 11 pero no para edge. ¿Alguien sabe de que otra manera se puede con estas limitaciones?

Saludos!

Comment: ¿De qué meta tag hablas?

Comment: Disculpa, pense que si lo habia puesto. Es este:<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />